# Merge values in map kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I need merge maps `mapA` and`mapB` with pairs of "name" - "phone number" into the final map, sticking together the values for duplicate keys, separated by commas. Duplicate values should be added only once.
I need the most idiomatic and correct in terms of language approach.

For example:

```
val mapA = mapOf("Emergency" to "112", "Fire department" to "101", "Police" to "102")
val mapB = mapOf("Emergency" to "911", "Police" to "102")
```

The final result should look like this:

```
{"Emergency" to "112, 911", "Fire department" to "101", "Police" to "102"}
```

This is my function:

```
fun mergePhoneBooks(mapA: Map<String, String>, mapB: Map<String, String>): Map<String, String> {
    val unionList: MutableMap <String, String> = mapA.toMutableMap()
    unionList.forEach { (key, value) -> TODO() } // here's I can't come on with a beatiful solution

    return unionList
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about:

```
val unionList = (mapA.asSequence() + mapB.asSequence())
    .distinct()
    .groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
    .mapValues { (_, values) -> values.joinToString(",") }
```

Result:

```
{Emergency=112,911, Fire department=101, Police=102}
```

This will:

- produce a lazy `Sequence` of both maps' key-value pairs
- group them by key (result: `Map<String, List<String>`)
- map their values to comma-joined strings (result: `Map<String, String>`)

Comment: Your example will print: `{Emergency=112,911, Fire department=101, Police=102,102}`, I guess it should be without repeating: `Police=102,102`

Comment: Be careful, this solution will fail to merge maps if they have same key and value, merging `{A=1, B=2}` and `{A=5, B=2}` will result into `{A=6, B=2}`

Comment: @AntonKushch well, yes, that is why I added `distinct` due to the OP's use case. You could remove it if you want to handle duplicates.

Comment: @Moira just to raise attention of blind copy/pasters :D

Answer (score 17):

You can do the following:

```
(mapA.keys + mapB.keys).associateWith {
    setOf(mapA[it], mapB[it]).filterNotNull().joinToString()
}
```

1. put all keys in a set
2. iterate over that set and and associate each element with the set of values
3. remove the null values from the value set
4. concatenate the elements in the value list using `joinToString()`.

Comment: damn... that `associateWith` was what I was looking for, but couldn't remember :-)

Answer (score 4):

While I looked at the other solutions I couldn't believe that there isn't an easier way (or ways as easy as the accepted answer without the need to recreate a `Map`, intermediate new lists, etc.). Here are 3 (of many ;-)) solutions I came up with:

1. Using the keys and mapping the values later:

   ```
    (mapA.keys.asSequence() + mapB.keys)
        .associateWith {
          sequenceOf(mapA[it], mapB[it]) // one of the sides may have null values in it (i.e. no entry in the map)...
              .filterNotNull()
              .distinct()
              .toList() // or if you require/prefer, do the following instead: joinToString()
        }
   ```
2. Using [`groupingBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html#groupingby) and [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html#fold) (or have a look at: [Group by key and fold each group simultaneously (KEEP)](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/group-and-fold.md)):

   ```
    (mapA.asSequence() + mapB.asSequence())
      .groupingBy { it.key }
      .fold({ _, _ -> mutableSetOf() }) { _, accumulator, element ->
        accumulator.apply {
          add(element.value)
        }
      }
   ```

   You could also just use an empty `String` instead and concatenate in the fold operation the way you need it. My first approach just used a `sequenceOf` instead of the `MutableSet`. It depends on what you require and what you want to do with the result afterwards. Be sure to use the overloaded `fold`-function that accepts an initial value selector, which creates a new initial value every time a new key is encountered. Thanks [xzt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273132/xzt) for noting it.
3. Using Javas [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)), but ignoring duplicates in the value and also just concatenating the values:

   ```
    val mergedMap: Map<String, String> = mapA.toMutableMap().apply {
      mapB.forEach { key, value ->
        merge(key, value) { currentValue, addedValue ->
          "$currentValue, $addedValue" // just concatenate... no duplicates-check..
        }
      }
    }
   ```

   This, of course, can also be written differently, but this way we ensure that mergedMap is still just a `Map<String, String>` when accessed again.

Comment: The grouping / fold combo is a bit hard to get but seems ultra powerful! From what I understood, the `accumulator`'s type is determined by what's in the the `fold(...)`. This answer deserves more upvotes

Comment: Be careful, option 2 is not correct - it provides single reference to mutable set as an initial value, therefore same reference will be used for each group, and you will not get what you expect. One of the ways to fix - use `fold` overload which takes producer of initial value as a first argument.

Comment: @xzt thank you for reporting it. Yes, this doesn't make sense. I should have seen it already while writing it. I will update the second part

Answer (score 3):

```
val mapA = mapOf("Emergency" to "112", "Fire department" to "101", "Police" to "102")
val mapB = mapOf("Emergency" to "911", "Police" to "102")

val result = (mapA.entries + mapB.entries)
    .groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
    .mapValues {(_, value) -> 
        value.joinToString(", ")
    }
```

Comment: Your result is `List<Pair<String, String>`, but it should be `Map<String, String>`.

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin you could do this:

```
fun main() {
    val map1 = mapOf("A" to 1, "B" to 2)
    val map2 = mapOf("A" to 5, "B" to 2)
    val result: Map<String, Int> = listOf(map1, map2)
        .fold(mapOf()) { accMap, map ->
            accMap.merge(map, Int::plus)
        }
    println(result) // Prints: {A=6, B=4}
}

private fun <T, V> Map<T, V>.merge(another: Map<T, V>, mergeFunction: (V, V) -> V): Map<T, V> =
    toMutableMap()
        .apply {
            another.forEach { (key, value) ->
                merge(key, value, mergeFunction)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach with universal map-merging helper function:

```
fun <K, V, R> Pair<Map<K, V>, Map<K, V>>.merge(merger: (V?, V?) -> R): Map<K, R> =
    (first.keys.asSequence() + second.keys.asSequence()).distinct()
        .associateWith { merger(first[it], second[it]) }

fun main() {
    val mapA = mapOf("Emergency" to "112", "Fire department" to "101", "Police" to "102")
    val mapB = mapOf("Emergency" to "911", "Police" to "102")
    val result = (mapA to mapB).merge { a, b -> 
            listOf(a, b).filterNotNull().distinct().joinToString(",", "(", ")") }
    println(result)
}
```

Output:

> {Emergency=(112,911), Fire department=(101), Police=(102)}

Answer (score 3):

A more generic approach (as this post comes up when searching for kotlin and merging maps):

```
fun <K, V1, V2, R> Map<K, V1>.mergeReduce(other: Map<K, V2>, reduce: (key: K, value1: V1?, value2: V2?) -> R): Map<K, R> =
    (this.keys + other.keys).associateWith { reduce(it, this[it], other[it]) }
```

It allows for Maps with different types of values to be merged, increased freedom with a custom reducer and increased readability.

Your problem can than be solved as:

```
mapA.mergeReduce(mapB) { _, value1, value2 -> listOfNotNull(value1, value2).joinToString(", ") }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write something like

```
fun Map<String, String>.mergeWith(another: Map<String, String>): Map<String, String> {
  val unionList: MutableMap<String, String> = toMutableMap()
  for ((key, value) in another) {
    unionList[key] = listOfNotNull(unionList[key], value).toSet().joinToString(", ")
  }
  return unionList
}

val mergedMap = mapA.mergeWith(mapB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
val mapA = mapOf("Emergency" to "112", "Fire department" to "101", "Police" to "102")
val mapB = mapOf("Emergency" to "911", "Police" to "102")

val result = mapA.toMutableMap()
mapB.forEach {
    var value = result[it.key]
    value = if (value == null || value == it.value) it.value else value + ", ${it.value}"
    result[it.key] = value
}
```

Or using **infix extension function**:

```
infix fun Map<String, String>.mergeWith(anotherMap: Map<String, String>): Map<String, String> {
    val result = this.toMutableMap()
    anotherMap.forEach {
        var value = result[it.key]
        value = if (value == null || value == it.value) it.value else value + ", ${it.value}"
        result[it.key] = value
    }
    return result
}

val result = mapA mergeWith mapB
```

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason not part of SDK.

Created my own extension:

```kotlin
fun <K,V>Map<K,Collection<V>>.merge(other: Map<K,Collection<V>>) =
    (this.keys + other.keys).associateWith {key ->
        setOf(this[key], other[key]).filterNotNull()
    }.mapValues { (a,b) -> b.flatten().toSet() 
}
```

Use like

```kotlin
val map1 = mapOf("a" to listOf(1,2,3), "b" to listOf(4,5,6))
val map2 = mapOf("a" to listOf(1,9), "b" to listOf(7))
val merge = map1.merge(map2) // {"a" = [1,2,3,9], "b" = [4,5,6,7]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not *exactly* answer the question posed by the OP, but I think many people coming to this post will, given its title, be looking for a simple way to merge two maps. The solution is that the `+` operator does the job and merges with deduplication. BUT in the event of a key being duplicated, the last value wins, you don't get the list of all values.

```
val mapA = mapOf("Emergency" to "112", "Fire department" to "101", "Police" to "102")
val mapB = mapOf("Emergency" to "911", "Police" to "102", "Ambulance" to "103")
val mapC = mapA + mapB
println(mapC)
```

gives

```
{Emergency=911, Fire department=101, Police=102, Ambulance=103}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution:

```
val result = (mapA + (mapB - mapA.keys)).mapValues {
    (setOf(it.value) + mapB[it.key]).filterNotNull().joinToString()
}
```

It creates a map of A plus the values from B that are not in A. Then it maps all values to a set and adds the value from B to that set, ultimately removing all `null` values from the set and transforming it into a list, which you can use to create the desired output format.

Comment: yes... but it takes still some time to understand it ;-) e.g. first I wondered what `mapB - mapA.keys` really does... (had to look up that `-`) and instead of a `setOf` i personally prefer `sequenceOf...distinct` (it says more clearly what is going on)... but that's just my opinion... :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
(mapA.data.asSequence() + mapB.asSequence())
   .map { Pair(it.key, it.value) }
   .toMap()
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation with your code to make others understand better.