# Kotlin toMap collector with duplicate keys

Tags: java, kotlin, java-stream

I'm looking for `Kotlin` analogue for Java stream collector `Collectors.toMap` with `mergeFunction` parameter.

For instance, in Java in order to count chars in String it's possible to use the following code snippet:

```
Map<Character, Integer> charsMap = s2.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

If we convert the Java snippet to Kotlin it looks rather ugly because of explicit types usage.

```
private fun countCharsV2(word: String): Map<Char, Int> {
    return word.chars()
        .mapToObj { it.toChar() }
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                Function { 1 },
                BinaryOperator { a: Int, b: Int -> Integer.sum(a, b) }
            )
        )
}
```

Is there a Kotlin collector with similar behaviour?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232530/merge-values-in-map-kotlin

Comment: If the intention is just to count chars: `word.toCharArray().toList().groupingBy { it }.eachCount()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case the easiest way to count char is:

```
val charsMap = s.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
```

In more general fashion `groupingBy` is a powerful tool which works as a replacement to `toMap` collector.