# Kotlin equivalent of Java's Map.merge

Tags: kotlin, collections, kotlin-native

I'm learning Kotlin Multiplatform and am trying to migrate a toy project of mine that was originally written for JVM, to Kotlin Native. One thing I'm stuck on is using the Java method [Map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

```
    @Test
    fun usingMerge() {
        val map = mutableMapOf("A" to 42, "B" to 13)
        map.merge("A", 20, ::max)
        map.merge("B", 15, ::max)
        map.merge("C", 10, ::max)
        val expected = mapOf("A" to 42, "B" to 15, "C" to 10)
        assertEquals(expected, map)
    }
```

Since this Java method is not available in Kotlin Native, I'm trying to find a suitable replacement. The code I've come up with is too verbose and inefficient:

```
    @Test
    fun withoutMerge() {
        val map = mutableMapOf("A" to 42, "B" to 13)
        map["A"].also { if (it == null || it < 20) map["A"] = 20 }
        map["B"].also { if (it == null || it < 15) map["B"] = 15 }
        map["C"].also { if (it == null || it < 10) map["C"] = 10 }
        val expected = mapOf("A" to 42, "B" to 15, "C" to 10)
        assertEquals(expected, map)
    }
```

Is there a way to write this that is shorter (approaching the conciseness of `merge`), that does not have repetition (for example, "A" and 20 are repeated twice in the code above), and that does not do two lookups of the same key?

Comment: There are several pure-Kotlin implementations in this answer that would work with Kotlin Native https://stackoverflow.com/q/54232530/4161471

Answer (score 0):

You could just write your own merge as a pure kotlin [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html) on the MutableMap interface.

This works for your example, it gets a bit more complex with generics of course:

```
fun MutableMap<String, Int>.merge2(k: String, v: Int, f: (Int, Int)->Int) {
    if (this.containsKey(k)){
        this[k]=f(this.getValue(k), v)
    } else {
        this[k]=v
    }
}

fun main() {
    val map = mutableMapOf("A" to 42, "B" to 13)
    map.merge2("A", 20, Math::max)
    map.merge2("B", 15, Math::max)
    map.merge2("C", 10, Math::max)
}
```

Comment: This is workable, but while Java's `merge` always makes only one key lookup, this makes at least 2 and sometimes 3 lookups of the same key.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <T, U> MutableMap<T, U>.mergeWith(key: T, value: U, fn: (U, U) -> U) {
  val v = this[key]
  this[key] = if (v == null) value else fn(v, value)
}

val map = mutableMapOf("A" to 42, "B" to 13)

map.mergeWith("A", 20, Math::max)
map.mergeWith("B", 15, Math::max)
map.mergeWith("C", 10, Math::max)

map.forEach(::println)
```

Comment: Thanks, this still does two lookups of the same key but it might be the best that can be done at present since there doesn't seem to be a merge function in the current version of the Kotlin Native implementation.